# IP Route: Prioritize one default route over the other by default

Tags: linux, networking, routing, bash, ip

I'm doing a lot of spooky networking shenanigans at work lately, and it's really messing with the routing on my laptop. Sometimes, it'll just decide that my default route now leads into the dev box and will flat out refuse to use my wireless connection to search google.

Naturally, I figured this was a routing issue, and popped off an `ip route show` which gave back this:

```
default via 10.0.5.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 20100 
default via 10.9.2.1 dev wlp1s1 proto dhcp metric 20600 
...
```

The `.9`net is the one connected to the internet. As you can see, that one is not at the top of the list. How can I tell my machine to use that route over the other one, connected to my dev box?

Comment: Have you tried changing the metric? Who sets up that route? (the .9)